# nomod errors when installing new angular modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

When I try to include `braintree-angular` into my gulp-angular project, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module notecards due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module braintree-angular due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'braintree-angular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I routinely run into issues loading newly install modules in gulp-angular projects, and I believe it comes from a general lack of understanding in how gulp works. The gulp portion of this project was setup by a coworker. If someone could explain why I continue to see issues like this, it would be much appreciated!

I have checked the following:

- The module is correctly installed in my `/node_modules` folder.
- The module appears correctly in my `package.json`.
- The entire folder is readable (I've previously had issues with file permissions causing this. This is not the case here.)
- The braintree-angular files are **not** being loaded by gulp.

**gulp/server.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
//var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');

var util = require('util');

var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
    browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

    var routes = null;
    if (baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
        routes = {
            '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
        };
    }

    var server = {
        baseDir: baseDir,
        routes : routes
    };

    /*
     * You can add a proxy to your backend by uncommenting the line below.
     * You just have to configure a context which will we redirected and the target url.
     * Example: $http.get('/users') requests will be automatically proxified.
     *
     * For more details and option, https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/v0.9.0/README.md
     */
    // server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/users', {target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', changeOrigin: true});

    browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
        startPath: '/',
        server   : server,
        browser: browser,
        host: '192.168.0.20',
        https: false,
        port   : parseInt(process.env.GULP_PORT) || 8684
    });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
    selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
    browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
    browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
    browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
    browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});

var gulp = require('gulp');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('src')
    .pipe(webserver({
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: true,
      open: true
    }));
});
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
/**
 *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
 *  The gulp tasks are splitted in several files in the gulp directory
 *  because putting all here was really too long
 */

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function (file) {
    return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function (file) {
    require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
 */
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build');
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "healthbydna",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.0.3",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "braintree-angular": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-extend": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-constant": "^1.1.0",
    "jotted": "^1.5.1",
    "lazypipe": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.16.0",
    "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
    "karma": "~0.13.10",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the fix to this very specific issue was to remove braintree-angular from node_modules and install it via bower. I also need to lock the version to `v1.3.0`. I am unsure **why** this fixed it, so an explanation would be great :)

Comment: Your gulp config is probably setup to automatically include scripts from your `bower.json` file into the build process for your web app. It is NOT automatically setup to include scripts from node modules in your `package.json` file, and for good reason. Node modules may not include scripts that would apply to your web app.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp is just a (very powerful) task runner, plain and simple. It does things you could do yourself, but you don't have the time for ;)

Node modules are not the same thing as Angular modules. Node modules have a broad scope and are for running general purpose code in the Node.js platform. That is, Javascript that runs outside of the typical web-browser setting. For example a desktop application, a loan calculator, a web server, a chat program, etc.

However, many Node modules are specifically for use with Angular and have a Bower counter-part. Bower packages are, indeed, for including directly in your webpage:

```
<script src="./bower_components/path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why is there both a Node module AND a Bower package for a web module, you might ask? That's because of bundlers like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and Webpack that let you actually use Node modules in your webpage. It does not appear that your project is setup for a bundler.

You want to either get the compiled js for your module (ideally by modifying your gulpfile to compile and/or concatenate the correct JS file from the node module's folder) or use Bower to download the already compiled JS, and modify the gulp file to include it into the concatenation process.

There are multiple files that make up the Gulp process for your project. Look for the 'build' task in one of those files. It should include the details about how vendor JS files are built. You want to modify it so that it is including the path to `braintree-angular`'s JS file (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

Gulp has nothing to do with Angular modules. From tasks you have published it is only used for localhost development and build not for any dependency injection.

Your problem is probably coming from not requiring dependency for module. You app.module should look something like this.

```
angular.module('app', [
    'angular-svg-round-progress'
]);
```

And also make sure module is loaded before your app else instantiation will fail.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't made this quite clear in my original post. The module is correctly loaded on the angular side. The issue came down to gulp not actually injecting the javascript files I needed it to.